# goBack() taking me all the way to first entry instead of where I want to be

Tags: reactjs, browser-history, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I'm creating a app where I Login/Logout have a home, about, profile etc. Its using react router as well, however when I log in I want the app to transition to the last route it was at, it works sometimes for example if I visit about, then login and log in, it takes me back to about, however if i visit the app root '/' and then go to login, and login, it takes me back to the first page I was ever on (which would be the default page when you open your browser or tab). I wrote it like this, and i think the way I may have done it is very naive. I did it in the render method which is called alot. I think it has sometime do with that but am not entirely sure. Was hoping for some advice, code:

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = UserStore.getState();
    this.context = context;
  }

render() {

    console.log(this.state.user.get('authenticated'));
    if(this.state.user.get('authenticated')){
        this.context.history.goBack();
    }

     return (
    //stuff
    )
```

Should i push a state into history every route i visit, I also noticed if I wait a bit before logging in sometimes it performs correctly, maybe it adds it into history a little late or it takes some time? Not entirely sure how to go about debugging it, console.log(this.context.history) just shows a bunch of its functions i guess I might be looking in the wrong place?

routes:

```
export default (
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="profile" component={Profile} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginSignupPage} />
    <Route path="channels" component={Channels} />
  </Route>
);
```

injecting react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Iso from 'iso';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

import alt from 'altInstance';
import routes from 'routes.jsx';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
window.React = React;
injectTapEventPlugin();

/*
 * Client side bootstrap with iso and alt
 */
Iso.bootstrap((state, _, container) => {
  alt.bootstrap(state);
  ReactDOM.render(<Router history={createBrowserHistory()} children={routes} />, container);
});
```

Comment: Can you please share code how you are injecting <Router/> into render? Which router version are you using? You are supposed to pass createHistory() to Router.

Comment: Yep, here you go, I do createBrowserHistory so it should be fine.

Comment: I learned today, doing it with createMemoryHistory works completely fine, however the url does not change i.e if go to localhost:3000/ and localhost:3000/about it will show the indexed route anyways and you can only navigate from there

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRedirect to='dashboard' />
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="profile" component={Profile} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginSignupPage} />
    <Route path="channels" component={Channels} />
</Route>
```

Change the Route like this may solve your problem. the path "/" should be a parent level route of "login" but not the same level

Comment: didnt really fix it, doing so also messed up the tab switches in material ui and the user interface, like the routes were changing but none of the graphical stuff was moving. I could host this on a real site if you want to see what it looks like.

Comment: I was thinking that the problem was caused by the route structure, now it seems not correct. I feel confused now too. -_-

Comment: Please put it up on a website.